# Why is AVAudioPlayer not responding?

Tags: iphone, audio, if-statement, avaudioplayer, audio-streaming

I'm a noob to iphone development (4th day in Xcode) and I'm trying to implement AvAudioPlayer and control it using the AwesomeMenu library.  I have no problem initializing and playing audio, but when I try to pause or stop the audio via the awesome menu controls the AVAudioPlayer doesn't respond. Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT

I was able to determine that my method isn't executing the conditional if/else statement within it.  This even more baffling. didSelectIndex is triggering but the if-statement within isn't.  Am I coding my conditional statement correctly?

MY CODE:

```
AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:url];
podcastPlayer = [[AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem] retain];
[podcastPlayer play];

//Control for AvAudioPlayer

- (void)AwesomeMenu:(AwesomeMenu *)menu didSelectIndex:(NSInteger)idx{
if (idx==0) {
    if(!podcastPlayer.isPlaying){
        podcastPlayer.play;
    }

}else if(idx==1){
    if(podcastPlayer.isPlaying){
        podcastPlayer.pause;
    }

}else if(idx==2){
    if(podcastPlayer.isPlaying){
        podcastPlayer.stop;
        podcastPlayer.release;

        GSCCAppDelegate *appDelegate = (GSCCAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

        [appDelegate.menu removeFromSuperview];

    }

}else if(idx==3){


}else if(idx==4){

}else if(idx==5){

}

NSLog(@"Select the index : %d",idx);
}
```

EDIT

```
- (void)AwesomeMenu:(AwesomeMenu *)menu didSelectIndex:(NSInteger)idx{
if (idx==0) {

    NSLog(@"Index 0"); //Doesn't work

}else if(idx==1){

    NSLog(@"Index 1"); //Doesn't work

}

}

NSLog(@"Select the index : %d",idx); //<--This Works.
```

}

Comment: is didSelectIndex triggering ?

Comment: yes, it is returning the appropriate  index.

Comment: what about the if(!podcastPlayer.isPlaying) condition? is it returns true when clicking index 0?

Comment: no, it isn't returning a value.  it is not seeing podcastPlayer variable at all within this method

Comment: oh..i see.. do one thing. declare AVPlayerItem *playerItem as a property and synthesis it. Don't declare as a local one.

Comment: It still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

declare `AVPlayerItem *playerItem` as a `property` and `synthesis` it.

Don't declare as a local one

Comment: Please. Check my edit. AvplayerItem isn't the problem, My if-statment doesn't work.

Comment: could you please send the sample code to ramshadram90@gmail.com ?